# Что за конструкция в React Native

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Изучаю React Native столкнулся с такой конструкцией не понимаю что значит

```
sectionHeaderHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
```

Comment: [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @Mr. Brightside ну я так понимаю это сокращение да? можете расписать как будет в несокращенном виде

Comment: в несокращенном function(r1, r2) {r1 !== r2 }, однако фишка тут именно в стрелке - это передача контекста. Если в функции необходимо обращение к родительскому контексту, то в "несокращенном" виде нужно будет ранее сохранить контекст в переменной, либо забиндить его. В случае стрелочной функции контекст внутрь функции можно передать просто **=>**

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, `return` забыли. Ну и думаю стоит оформить ваш комментарий в виде ответа. Возможно он будет полезен кому-то еще

Comment: вопрос не столько про реакт, сколько про [tag:ecmascript-6]. стоит переметить

Comment: @DmitriySimushev сейчас сделаем

Comment: Будет выглядеть так [ссылка](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=%7B%0A%20%20sectionHeaderHasChanged%3A%20(r1%2C%20r2)%20%3D%3E%20r1%20!%3D%3D%20r2%0A%7D).

В целом можете поиграться в REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

В "обычном" виде Ваша конструкция будет такой:

```
function (r1, r2) {
  return r1 !== r2;
}
```

Однако, фишка тут именно в стрелке - это передача контекста. Если в функции необходимо обращение к родительскому контексту, то в "несокращенном" виде нужно будет ранее сохранить контекст в переменной, либо забиндить его. В случае стрелочной функции контекст внутрь функции можно передать просто **=>**

Ну и как Вам правильно написали в комментариях, тут вопрос действительно про ES6

Answer (score 1):

Если вам непонятно имеено назначение этого метода, то в нём сказано, что в генераци элементов компонента , генерация будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока следующий элемент списка не будет равен предыдущему.